# How to update data from mssql to mysql on linked server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER" returned
>   message "Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been
>   changed since it was last read.".

```
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYLINKEDSERVER" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]".
```

The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row was last fetched or resynchronized.

```
DECLARE @Counter nvarchar(1024),
        @TSQL varchar(8000)

SET @Counter = 0

WHILE (@Counter <=(select Top 1 ID from mydb.dbo.tbl1 order by ID desc))

BEGIN

    set nocount on

    IF EXISTS(select Top 1 ID from mydb.dbo.tbl1 where ID = @Counter)

    BEGIN

        SELECT  @TSQL   = 'UPDATE OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVER,''select * from mydb2.tbl2 where tbl1_id is not null and tbl1_id= ' + @Counter + ''')' + 'set employees = ' + CAST((select t.employees from mydb.dbo.tbl1 as t where t.ID = @Counter) as nvarchar)

        EXEC (@TSQL)
        SELECT @Counter=@Counter+1
    END

    ELSE BEGIN

        SELECT @Counter=@Counter+1

    END

END
```

Comment: add `PRINT @TSQL` before EXEC and paste here the generated query.

Comment: first row: UPDATE OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVER,'select * from mydb2.tbl2 where tbl1_id is not null and tbl1_id= 4') set employees = 168

Comment: Did you see this?  Check the last post : 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/266c5992-6f02-4cab-89d7-003b2fdfeed2/openquery-update-and-optimistic-concurrency?forum=transactsql

Comment: Yes. But not solved. because of odbc driver.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC Driver advanced options.
Flag on don't cache result fof foward only...
LFag on Return matched row...